# PostgreSQL - inserting values into a non-existing table with variables

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create an artificial table in postgreSQL, but the problem is when I created the select with variables it always returns error:

```html
-- Declare variables
DO $$
BEGIN
      v_version_ID            INT := 1;
      v_version_number        VARCHAR(255) := '1.0';
      v_version_creation_date DATE := '2024-01-29';
      v_version_close_date    DATE := '9999-12-31';
   BEGIN
      -- Insert values using variables
      INSERT INTO attendence_list (version_ID, version_number, version_creation_date, version_close_date)
      VALUES (v_version_ID, v_version_number, v_version_creation_date, v_version_close_date);
   END;
END $$;

-- Select data from the table
SELECT * FROM attendence_list;
```

```
unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN v_version_ID INT := 1" LINE 2: DO $$ ^
```

Probably it is beginner question, but I tried to read the documentation and search for answers, but I am puzzled.

Comment: Replace your first BEGIN with DECLARE. v_version_close_date is better off using infinity or null, instead of a fake future date.

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens I tried, but I got another error message: 
unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ DECLARE v_version_ID INT := 1" LINE 2: DO $$ ^

btw I am using 16.1 version

Comment: You also use END twice, remove one. Keep it simple and use the manual while learning: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html